# How to export IE cookies using perl?

Tags: windows, perl, internet-explorer, cookies

I know that there is a option within Internet Explorer that I could use the manually export cookies. However, is it possible to have a Perl script to automate IE to export cookies to a text file or by using command shell?

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it with Internet Explorer, but when I've had to do this task for other browsers, I found the file that the cookies are already in and parsed that directly. It's why there are so many HTTP::Cookies::* modules in [my CPAN account](https://metacpan.org/author/BDFOY).

There are also various [Win32 modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=win32&size=20) to let you control Windows applications from Perl through the Windows APIs. I made [a list of some examples](http://www.windowsperl.com/2014/04/04/looking-for-win32ole-examples/) that use [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/release/Win32-OLE), for instance. There's one that plays Minesweeper for you!